# Appending item to all sublist of a list in Python

Tags: python

Here are my datasets:

```
R = [["yyy", "3"],["www", "4"],["eee","3"],["zzz", "2"]]
```

I am trying to append one item ('-1') to all sublists of a list (R) to get a new list (new_R), and keep R unchanged:

```
print(new_R)
output:
[['yyy', '3', '-1'],
 ['www', '4', '-1'],
 ['eee', '3', '-1'],
 ['zzz', '2', '-1']]

print(R)
output:
[["yyy", "3"],["www", "4"],["eee","3"],["zzz", "2"]]
```

I tried:

```
new_R = [x.append('-1') for x in R]
```

and

```
new_R = list(map(lambda x: x.append('-1'), R))
```

However, the results of R and new_R are not expected:

```
print(new_R)
output:
[None, None, None, None]

print(R)
output:
[['yyy', '3', '-1'],
 ['www', '4', '-1'],
 ['eee', '3', '-1'],
 ['zzz', '2', '-1']]
```

Looking for explanation and solution!
Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `x.append(-1)` try `x + [-1]`. Your own results are explained by the fact that `append` mutates a list and returns `None`.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for your explaination!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append` operates in place and returns `None`, so you don't want that (it's why your solutions create lots of `None`s in the new `list` while modifying the original `list`). Simplest solution is just `list` concatenation, e.g.:

```
new_R = [x + ['-1'] for x in R]
```

or (with [newer syntax for 3.5 and higher](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), and potentially fewer temporaries) construct a new `list` by unpacking the old one plus an extra value:

```
new_R = [[*x, '-1'] for x in R]
```

Comment: Side-note: In testing, on Python 3.8.5 and 3.9.0 (both x64 for Linux), the unpacking solution was faster. Not a *lot* faster, just ~20% reduction in runtime. Either one is fine though; this is highly unlikely to be your bottleneck.

Comment: Why is unpacking the list faster than concatenating here?

Comment: Thanks! This really helpful!!

Comment: @JoshuaNixon My guess would be because it avoids creating the temporary list `[-1]`.

Comment: I always assumed unpacking a list would be quite a heavy task

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: kaya3's comment is part of it (though in prior to Python 3.9, it instead creates a `(-1,)` implicitly; `tuple`s are slightly more efficient though, and it does the building via dedicated bytecodes that don't do dynamic dispatch, where `+` does). In Python 3.9, it doesn't even make the one-`tuple`, it just introduced dedicated byte code for the building that remove the need for it; excluding `LOAD`s, the unpack is `BUILD_LIST`, `LIST_EXTEND`, `LIST_APPEND`, the concatenation is `BUILD_LIST`, `BINARY_ADD`, where the latter requires more indirection, less use of concrete APIs.

Comment: I could see it going either way.  They're close enough to equivalent that I'd suggest choosing the one that looks nicer to you.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: Unpacking in the generalized unpacking context is literally just the `LIST_EXTEND` bytecode, which calls the concrete API for `list.extend` (`_PyList_Extend`) directly. It doesn't actually unpack, it just lets `list` iterate and expand itself as normal.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That makes sense. Appreciate the explanation!

Comment: @JoshuaNixon I agree with you. When I working on combining two lists (a, b) into one (c), I found [ *a, *b] is significantly slower than a.extend(b). Maybe the reason is that array is faster than list :)

Comment: @Liang: `extend` is faster when you want to modify `a` in place (it doesn't need to build a new `list` at all, and for small `b`, may not even need to reallocate). In your case though, you want to build a new `list` and leave `a`/`b` untouched; you can't use `extend` directly (and replacing it with `.copy()` followed by `.extend()` would make it slower than unpacking; it would do the same work, via less efficient means).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for your explanation! I really want to vote for you, but I don't have enough "reputation". Thanks again!

Comment: Done! I am new to stackoverflow! Thanks!